# Unable to upload when NGINX is in front of webserver

Tags: nginx

I have a web server that accepts file upload, it works fine when client accesses it directly without NGINX in front.

With NGINX in front, the upload file does not seem to get pass NGINX.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defaul**

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            client_max_body_size 0;
    }
```

Above, the snippet of the proxy pass to the underlying web server. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you debug this a bit further?  First, determine whether the problem is between the client and Nginx, or Nginx and the upstream server.  Also, what specifically do you mean when you say the upload file does not get past Nginx?  Are there errors?

Comment: Content/data is not arriving at the application server, right now I am using NGINX Unit as a web/app server. When running the app server locally using Unit also, the server works as expected, since when testing locally I don't use Nginx in front of Unit. So it is safe to assume that NGINX Unit app server is not the problem here (I think).

Comment: Furthermore, when accessing the resource, on localhost, direct to Unit, the response is 201, but with Nginx, it returns 204 (same client request) -- and while the app server, Unit, the app itself there is no response 204 programmed. So I think the problem is Nginx is not passing the data / upload file and just returns 204 instead.

Comment: Please be specific.  "Content/data is not arriving at the application server", what **exactly** do you mean?  Is the request not getting there at all?  Or is the request getting there but without any POST body?  Or, is the POST body there, but missing file data?  It isn't even clear from your question right now what your request body looks like.  Is it a multipart form?  Is it just the file in the request body?